# I keep getting "Error: could not find or load main class" when I try to run java applications from command prompt

Tags: java, classpath

I've looked up why and I saw that the problem is either with not specifying the package or with the classpath. I don't use any packages so it must be with the classpath and I read some java documentation on it and I thought I figured out where to set it but it still doesn't work. I did

```
set classpath = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\*;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\*;
```

but that didn't work, so I guess I have no clue what to set the classpath to. Am I just setting it to the wrong folder or is there a more significant problem?

a)

```
public class Hello_World{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

b) I already ran javac Hello_world.java and got a class file and now I'm running java hello_world

c) the error message "Error: could not find or load main class Hello_World"

Comment: You probably want to include the current directory `.` in the classpath, unless your class file is in the JDK `lib` or `bin` directory.

Comment: Please show us a) your code; b) how you're trying to run it; c) the error message. Currently we don't have enough information to help you - we know you're doing *something* wrong, but we don't know what...

Comment: I included said edits into the question

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you shouldn't need to worry about adding `lib` and `bin` if Java is in your path. If your class is in the same directory as you are running java from, and no package as you say, then you should be able to do:

```
$ java Hello_World
```

or add current directory to classpath:

```
$ java -cp . Hello_World
```

Comment: am I supposed to include that $ in the command prompt. Because it says it is not recognized

Comment: No, don't use $ - that IS the command prompt ;) ie. you write `java Hello_World`

Comment: Yeah thats what I've been doing, but it doens't work

Comment: what happens when you type just `java` in shell? Did you compile the source first into a class using `javac`?

Comment: when i type just java it gives me a list of commands that deal with java, and yes I did compile it with javac first